# ExtJS MVC can't bind TreePanel from TreeStore (standard JSON server structure)

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, extjs-mvc

In my `ExtJS` application (**4.2.1**) all my responses from server has a default structure.

I'm trying to fill a `TreeStore` from my server method but I can't.

This is my server `JSON` response:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "text": "Test 1",
      "id": "1",
      "leaf": true,
      "cls": null,
      "children": [
        {
          "text": "Test 11",
          "id": "11",
          "leaf": true,
          "cls": null,
          "children": null
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "Test 2",
      "id": "2",
      "leaf": true,
      "cls": null,
      "children": null
    },
    {
      "text": "Test 3",
      "id": "3",
      "leaf": true,
      "cls": null,
      "children": null
    },
    {
      "text": "Test 4",
      "id": "4",
      "leaf": true,
      "cls": null,
      "children": null
    },
    {
      "text": "Test 5",
      "id": "5",
      "leaf": true,
      "cls": null,
      "children": null
    }
  ],
  "message": "",
  "num": 1,
  "success": true,
  "code": null
}
```

My TreeStore looks like this:

```
Ext.define('App.store.menu.ReportMenu', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    autoLoad: true,
    requires: [
        'App.model.menu.ReportMenu',
        'App.proxy.CustomProxy'
    ],

    model: 'App.model.menu.ReportMenu',
    proxy:
        {
            type: 'customproxy',
            api: {
                read: '/api/Security/GetUserReportsMenu'
            }
        }
});
```

My model looks like this:

```
Ext.define('App.model.menu.ReportMenu', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty: 'id',

    fields: [{
        name: 'text'
    }, {
        name: 'id'
    }, {
        name: 'leaf',
        type: 'boolean'
    }, {
        name: 'cls'
    }, {
        name: 'children'
    }],

});
```

And my `TreePanel` in my view is this one:

```
{
 xtype: 'treepanel',
            title: 'Reports List',
            itemId: 'rptList',
            glyph: Glyphs.LIST,
            width: 300,
            border: 1,
            store: Ext.create('App.store.menu.ReportMenu'),
            displayField: 'text',
            useArrows: false,
            rootVisible: true,
}
```

And this is the only thing I can see in my TreePanel:

[image]

Any clue on what I'm doing wrong?  I can't change the server JSON response structure because it's a standard in the whole application.

Comment: What if you add json reader with `root:'data'`?

Answer (score 0):

In your previous code missing **reader** in proxy:

```
Ext.define('App.store.menu.ReportMenu', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    autoLoad: true,
    requires: [
        'App.model.menu.ReportMenu',
        'App.proxy.CustomProxy'
    ],

    model: 'App.model.menu.ReportMenu',
    proxy:
       {               
           type: 'customproxy',
           api: {
              read: '/api/Security/GetUserReportsMenu'
           }
       }
   }
);
```

The code after insert **reader** definition:

```
Ext.define('App.store.menu.ReportMenu', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    autoLoad: true,
    requires: [
        'App.model.menu.ReportMenu',
        'App.proxy.CustomProxy'
    ],

    model: 'App.model.menu.ReportMenu',
    proxy:
       {

           type: 'customproxy',
           api: {
              read: '/api/Security/GetUserReportsMenu'
           },
           reader:{
              type:'json'
              ,root:'data'
           }
      }
);
```